# Sum of K smallest elements in Binary search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

Could anyone please suggest, what is wrong with this below code for finding the sum of k smallest elements in a BST? It is returning the sum for all the nodes in the tree.

```
public int findSum(Node root, int k){
            int count = 0;
            return findSumRec(root, k, count);
        }

        private int findSumRec(Node root, int k, int count) {

            if(root == null)
                return 0;
            if(count > k)
                return 0;

            int sum = findSumRec(root.left, k, count);
            if(count >= k)
                return sum;

            sum += root.data;
            count++;

            if(count >= k)
                return sum;
            return sum + findSumRec(root.right, k, count);
            }
```

Comment: i would have reused the code for inorder traversal for this limiting the traversing to only 7 elems

Comment: What is and example input with expected output? What output are you getting instead?

Comment: your code is adding all the numbers in the tree, where is the logic to verify if it is the smallest

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala : I have used the inorder traversal approach. the moment count becomes equal to k(upto which i need to find the sum), the sum is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Java is a pass by value language, so changing the value of `count` in one method call doesn't change the value of `count` of the method that called it.

Suppose at some point during the recursion, when `k` is `5` and `count` is `4`, you are calling:

```
        int sum = findSumRec(root.left, 5, 4);
```

Suppose that this call increases the `count` passed to it to `5`, and returns some `sum`.

Now you are back to the method that called `findSumRec(root.left, 5, 4)` and you check:

```
        if(4 >= 5)
            return sum;
```

Even though the recently returned recursive call brought `count` up to `5`, which means you should be done, the caller still sees `count` as `4` (since it's not the same `count` variable), and therefore the traversal of the tree continues until you visit all the nodes of the tree and sum all of them.

You must use some mutable instance to modify the `count`.

For example, you can use an array having a single element:

```
public int findSum(Node root, int k){
    int[] count = {0};
    return findSumRec(root, k, count);
}
```

and

```
private int findSumRec(Node root, int k, int[] count) {
    ...
    change each count to count[0]
    ...
}
```

EDIT: I just tested your code with my suggested correction, and it works.

```
public int findSum(Node root, int k) {
    int[] count = {0};
    return findSumRec(root, k, count);
}

private int findSumRec(Node root, int k, int[] count) {

    if(root == null)
        return 0;
    if(count[0] > k)
        return 0;

    int sum = findSumRec(root.left, k, count);
    if(count[0] >= k)
        return sum;

    sum += root.val;
    count[0]++;

    if(count[0] >= k)
        return sum;
    return sum + findSumRec(root.right, k, count);
}
```

The point is that all the recursive method calls to `findSumRec` must share the value of the `count` variable and be able to change it. This is not possible when `count` is a primitive variable passed to the method, since each method gets a different copy of that variable.

Using an array is one option. Another option is to use a member variable of the class that contains your methods instead of passing it as an argument. This way it can still be `int`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more on this. Because as per my understanding only the initial call is using "count = 0". Post that first call, remaining all recursive calls would be done using the updated value of count(count++ for each node addition).

Comment: @aman_coder I elaborated my answer. I tested your code with my fix, and it works, so that was the only issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something like this, Here is my code in java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

  public static class Node {
    int val;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Node(int data) {
      this.val = data;
      this.left = null;
      this.right = null;
    }
  }

  public static int sum_ans = 0;

  public static int count_k_smallest_sum(Node root, int count, int k)
  {
    if(count>=k)
    {
      return 100005;
    }
    if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
    {
      sum_ans += root.val;
      return count+1;
    }
    int cnt = count;
    if(root.left != null)
    {
      cnt = count_k_smallest_sum(root.left, cnt, k);
    }
    if(cnt >= k)
    {
      return 100005;
    }
    sum_ans += root.val;
    cnt++;

    if(cnt >= k)
    {
      return 100005;
    }

    if(root.right != null)
    {
      cnt = count_k_smallest_sum(root.right, cnt, k);
    }

    return cnt;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Node root = new Node(10);
    Node left1 = new Node(5);
    Node right1 = new Node(11);
    Node left2 = new Node(3);
    Node right2 =new Node(12);
    Node left3 = new Node(2);
    Node right3 = new Node(7);
    Node right4 = new Node(4);
    root.left = left1;
    root.right = right1;
    right1.right = right2;
    left1.left = left2;
    left1.right = right3;
    left2.left = left3;
    left2.right = right4;
    int cnt = count_k_smallest_sum(root, 0, 3);
    System.out.println(sum_ans);
  }
}
```

See my code logic in the method - count_k_smallest_sum.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hey @zenwraight, thank you for providing the solution and it is working absolutely fine as well. However i am interested in finding the mistake in the approach which i am trying to implement. I am just trying to use recursive inorder traveral approach to achieve this(very much similar to yours). The suggestion provided by Eran might help in that, but still i am having few doubts.